# why my anchor padding does not work on webkit browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, safari, webkit, anchor, padding

I have a navigation using anchor tags.

It's pretty basic, before of each section, I use

```
<a id="myid" class="anchor"></a>
```

and link it to my main nav.

In the css, i have:

```
.anchor {padding-top: 45px;}
```

To prevent my sticky nav to overlap each section (my nav is 45px height).

My problem : though it's working fine on FF, Chrome and Safari seems to be ignoring the padding-top I set.

Sorry if this is a basic/newbe question, but I could not find the answer.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display:inline-block` to your .anchor CSS.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ca9us/)

Comment: Side note: usage with li's see [here](http://uncorkedstudios.com/2011/12/12/how-to-fix-the-ie7-and-inline-block-css-bug/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Though what's strange (to me) is that - without the display: inline-block - FF does not "add" the 45px, it only "moves" 45px down (dunno if I'm clear... :S). Anyways, I'll use the display: inline-block, even if it added 45px to my design. :) Thanks again for your quick reply !!

Comment: I'm running Firefox 15 (haven't updated in a while), and it works the same as it does in Safari and Chrome - no visible padding without display:inline-block. Are you possibly in quirks mode?